# SL4's ListBoxDragDropTarget modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl) functionalities.

Tags: silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit, modifier-key

I've recently started playing with Silverlight 4, and in one of my projects I'm required to use drag & drop functionality.

I use the `ListBoxDragDropTarget`, which is not a problem.
However I was wondering what are the default use of the modifier keys.  I was able to understand that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> means copy, but couldn't find the use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or when combining them (I saw that when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the icon changes, but I don't understand what it does).

I searched a bit on the web, but didn't found any explanation of the default behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the source for the Silverlight Toolkit, and found that the supported modifier keys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, plus the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> tries to do a copy.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> tries to do a `Link` (not quite sure what that means).
- I'm not sure what <kbd>Alt</kbd> tries to do... Perhaps a `move`.

Overall, these are going to be suggestions, but may not be allowed based on what the droptarget's `AllowedEffects` are.

Comment: Thanks Robaticus !  Move is the default behavior when you don't press any modifier key.  As for the link, I made some tests, and don't see any difference with a "simple" move.  Anyway, what I only need in my project is move and copy, and pressing ctrl to copy is a good option in my case.  Thanks for your answer !